# Linting Salt states without running them

Tags: salt-stack

I am using Saltstack in a homelab, and I often find myself checking in slightly-broken rules when testing them. I would like to be able to check them for validity, and otherwise lint them, locally and on a Jenkins instance, but I can't find any documentation about how I might do so. Is there something I'm missing?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Syntax issues are multi-layered in Salt (i.g. Jinja -> YAML -> state function args) and there is no tool to cover them all.

The fast answer based on [this related issue](https://github.com/saltstack/salt/issues/802#issuecomment-70004550) is to trigger the multi-layered parsing:

```
salt-call state.show_highstate      | tee highstate.output.yaml
salt-call state.show_sls [state_id] | tee state_id.output.yaml
```

The `show_*` functions display state data as minion sees it before execution.

Using `salt-call` on minion side  (instead of `salt` on master side) often provides better debug options - this is mostly a preference.

The problems may also be in pillar or grains (check that all required data is compiled and exists as expected):

```
salt-call pillar.items | tee pillar.output.yaml
salt-call grains.items | tee grains.output.yaml
```

Just like [@cyfur01 already mentioned](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31235529/441652), running states directly (with test mode or not) is the last step to troubleshoot:

```
salt-call state.highstate      test=True | tee highstate.output.yaml
salt-call state.sls [state_id] test=True | tee state_id.output.yaml
```

Comment: Excellent expansion on @cyfu01's answer, thanks so much!

Answer (score 6):

Salt states support a [testing interface](http://docs.saltstack.com/en/latest/ref/states/testing.html). For example:

```
salt '*' state.highstate test=True
```

This should run the states and tell you everything they *would* do without actually changing anything -- effectively it's a dry run. While it's not directly a linting tool, it does verify that Salt is able to parse and run everything.

Answer (score 4):

The `test` option is heavy for linting YAML configs. Instead try creating a precheckin script that includes something like this:

```
salt-call state.highstate --file-root=$PWD --local --retcode-passthrough mocked=True
```

- `--file-root` allows you to specify the location of your current
  checkout
- `--local` indicates that the action should not run through
  the master
- `--retcode-passthrough` causes this command to exit non-zero if any rule cannot be constructed
- `mock=True` processes all of the rules, but does not initiate connections. This is a new feature in [2015.8.5](https://docs.saltstack.com/en/latest/topics/releases/2015.8.5.html#core-changes). An alternate method is to run `state.show_highstate`

Comment: This will work for very basic setups, but will not support an external pillar (even if that is just a separate directory in the same checkout).

Answer (score 2):

I've been searching a while for a good way to achieve this QA stuff on salt state, and my best answer so far is :

1. Using jenkins to launch jobs (through ssh), based on a dev git branch that:

   - Provision a lxc on our lab proxmox private cloud (in the exact same manner we do this in prod)
   - Using salt reactors the container get its config (as it would on prod)
   - Using testinfra to run unit test on the built and config'ed container
   - Finally if everything went OK destroy the container, if not keep it alive for a morning debugging session :)
2. We also run a linting jenkins jobs as :

   ```
   for state in $(sudo /usr/bin/salt-call cp.list_states | awk '{print $2}' | grep -v "^top$"); do sudo /usr/bin/salt-call --retcode-passthrough state.show_sls ${state} ; done
   ```

I still have some issue getting the correct return code for this last linting job (because of ssh and so on).

**This process as a whole ensure :**

1. Our provisioning process is OK
2. Our code base (state + pillar) is working as expected
3. We can merge dev to prod with a great confidence ratio

The real good point of testinfra is that it can use a salt connection backend which allow testinfra to connect to container without the need to deploy ssh key, or anything else (as we are using salt-cloud for the initial provisioning)

More on testinfra [salt connection backend](http://testinfra.readthedocs.io/en/latest/backends.html#salt), testinfra [salt module](http://testinfra.readthedocs.io/en/latest/modules.html#testinfra.modules.salt.Salt).

This not perfect but still it does quite a good job.